# load record by predicate/lambda via vb.net linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

im pretty confused about lambdas and actually im not even sure i need them here

what im trying to do here is write a function that will return an object from a certain table with a certain criteria

so lets say i can write

```
function GetRecord(TableName as string,Criteria as string) as object
'do the linq-stuff
end function
```

now i dont care if the paremeters are strings or lambdas or whatever, but the end result must be that at runtime i dont know which table and which criteria will be used

as sometimes i need to get a customer record by email and sometimes a product by id etc.

if possible i would prefer returning a list of matching objects and then i would just use .firstordefault when i want 1 (such as by id...)

thank you , as always, for taking the time to read this and answer!

all the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [`Dynamic LINQ`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)?

### Example:

[image: Dynamic LINQ]

Comment: hey, youve already answered some of my questions. Thanks!  anyway here u still need to know the table name (products) but ths answer reminds me i can use executequery probalbly. something i forgot about somehow! i accepted the answer as its probably what ill use. thansk and keep up ur excellent work!

Comment: Thank you for appreciation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Parsing an expression tree can be a challenging but rewarding method of solving this issue.  I think it's overkill and I'd go with Dynamic Linq as decyclone mentioned.

A benefit of parsing the expression tree, however, is that you can have compile time checking of the submitted criteria.

Here are some articles that helped me.

How to: Implement an Expression Tree Visitor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(VS.90).aspx

Building a custom IQueryable Provider: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx

Walkthrough: Creating an IQueryable LINQ Provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158(v=VS.90).aspx

Expression Tree Basics: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx

Comment: i thought about this 100 times already, but never had the guts to start using it. it would be excelent for search filters. one day i guess... thansk anyways